# Use default csv file when no file uploaded to shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where the user uploads two csv files - a reference data set and a test data set. The data sets are manipulated in reactive expressions in the server code, and then the output from that is used to produce tables and plots.

I want to use a default reference data set if no reference data set is uploaded. How do I get my reactive expression to return the default data if no data has been uploaded?

I've tried loading my data at the beginning of the app (calling it 'default.ref.data' and then using the following in the server code:

```
ref.data=reactive({
   req(input$ref.upload)
   # read the data frame that has been uploaded
   df.ref1 <- read.csv(input$ref.upload$datapath) 

   #do some stuff

   return(df.ref1)
   if(is.null(input$files)) return(default.ref.data)
})
```

The last line is aiming to return my default file that I read in earlier if no input file is uploaded. This is not working. What should I be doing? Should I be looking at it from a different angle?

Comment: `req` wants not NULL values so your condition is wrong, return is empty. And you can only have one return in the reactive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                          multiple = FALSE,
                          accept = c("text/csv",
                                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                     ".csv")), tableOutput("tbl"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  get_file_or_default <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file1)) {
      mtcars
    } else {
      read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    }
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable(get_file_or_default())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```